# Linkbutton id inside a repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a linkbutton inside a repeater, and I need it to have an id in order to trigger a modal popup extender, but it is not working since the id is not correct due to the repeater.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repeaterSessions" runat="server" OnItemCommand="repeaterSessions_OnItemCommand">
           <ItemTemplate>
               <p>
               <%# ((Academia.SessionEN)Container.DataItem).Title %>
               <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" Text="Select" CommandArgument=<%#Eval("id") %>></asp:LinkButton>
               </p>
            </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:Repeater>
```

After this we have the modal popup extender which triggers the linkbutton1:

```
   <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="LinkButton1_ModalPopupExtender" runat="server" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="LinkButton1" PopupControlID="Panel1">
```

I tried to add a new linkbutton1 outside the repeater with the id linkbutton1, and it works, but I'd like to know if it is possible to trigger this from inside the repeater.
Thanks everyone!

EDIT: It would also be a possibility to trigger the modal popup extender from the code behind function, but I don't know how to do it either.

Comment: Pretty sure you still need to have quotes around this property.  CommandArgument=<%#Eval("id") %>   ------>   CommandArgument="<%#Eval("id") %>"

Comment: @Seano666 I changed it but the problem is still the same, i don't know how to trigger the modal popup extender inside the repeater

Comment: Does [this MSDN link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/phaniraj/2007/02/20/show-and-hide-modalpopupextender-from-javascript/) help? Have each LinkButton call a JavaScript function to show and hide the modal?

Comment: @j.f. thanks a lot, in the link I found a .Show() function to show the ModalPopupExtender

Comment: No problem. Did it work for you?

Comment: @j.f. yes, thanks a lot.